# How to convert inmemory file to file object

Tags: django

I am uploading a file and then trying to read it but I am getting

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile
```

my view function is

```
def upload(request,pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            filehandle=request.FILES['file']

            if filehandle:
                print("File recieved")
            workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filehandle)
            worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
            rows = []
            #Some Operartion
            workbook.close()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/products/')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like that. open_workbook can read your file from request by .read() by param file_contents

```
import xlrd

def upload(request,pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        filehandle=request.FILES['file']
        workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename='test.xlsx', file_contents=filehandle.read())
        worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
```