# Trouble loading open_workbook from xlrd in my program

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlrd

I'm really not sure why I keep getting errors when i used open_workbook from xlrd... the idea is i want to create an a webpage that uploads an excel file and open that file in through my code to process the data. Is there a way to workaround this?

```
    def upload(request):
         if "GET" == request.method:
                messages.warning(request, 'no file uploaded')
                return render(request, 'uploadpage/upload.html', {})
            else:
                excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]

                wb = xlrd.open_workbook(excel_file)

                # iterating over the rows and
                # getting value from each cell in row


                sheet = wb.sheet_by_name("Summary")

                #looping through each rows in a column to find the seller's info 
                # and storying the values in an array
                seller_info = []
                count = 1
                cfirst, clast = 1,2
                while (count < 6):
                    for colx in range(cfirst, clast):
                        count = count+1
                        seller_info.append(sheet.col_values(colx, start_rowx=count-1, end_rowx=count))

 return render(request, 'uploadpage/upload.html', {"excel_data": seller_info})
```

Here is the front end code

```
  <div id='upload-container' >

                <span>
                    <h2>Upload Here</h2>
                </span>


                    <div id='input'>
                        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="file" name="excel_file">
                        <div id='btn'>
                            <button type="submit">Upload File</button> 
                        </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

This is the error message I'm getting

TypeError at /
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 2.2.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InMemoryUploadedFile

Comment: Why are you not using "pandas" to process the data? Much easier more convenient

Comment: For future readers, a good answer to this is found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885595/how-to-convert-inmemory-file-to-file-object